# Area inside a closed loop curve in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-integration

Given a plot in matplotlib, how to find the area covered by them(integrated area)?

[image]

Comment: what function gives you that graph?

Comment: If you have the functions to plot the graphs, then you can probably derive an analytical (i.e. exact) solution.  Otherwise, you'll need to settle for a numerical approximation using something like the Trapezoidal Rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) or something more sophisticated.

Comment: This is a measured data. hence I do not have any function. I am trying with integ.trapz

Comment: Do you have the underlying data points, or just the graph? :)

Comment: You can easily calculate areas of arbitrary polygons with shapely

Comment: @NPE I have the data points

Comment: @Martin  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

use [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)

[here's a quick rundown](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120462/calculating-area-of-polygon-inside-region) in a different QA

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point
>>> a = Point(1, 1).buffer(1.5)
>>> b = Point(2, 1).buffer(1.5)
>>> c = a.intersection(b)
>>> c.area
4.11619859013966
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21331672)

Comment: added example from the refferenced QA

Answer (score 0):

If you have x, y points I assume that you are working on a discreate function rather than continious function. If you are sure that there will be only 2 point respect to x axis you can sum difference of the y axis.

```
import numpy as np 

point_list = np.array([(1, 3), [1, 5], (2, 3), (2 ,10)])
_sum = 0
for point in point_list:
    indexes = np.where([points[0] for points in point_list] == point[0])[0]
    _sum += abs(point_list[indexes[0]][1] - point_list[indexes[1]][1]) / 2
print(_sum)
```